# Subversion - Can't commit message & View History

Tags: visual-studio, svn, commit

Which tortoise subversion which integrated with Visual Studio can be able to enter messages while committing, view history of others and my file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you're describing is not specific to Tortoise, it's a standard functionality of Subversion itself. However, you have the option of [integrating TortoiseSVN in Visual Studio](https://tortoisesvn.net/visualstudio.html) as well as just using [VisualSVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) if you're trying to integrate a SVN client into VS.

That being said, if you're using TortoiseSVN, simply right click on the file folder you want to commit and click **SVN Commit...** and specify your comment as normal. To view the history of a file or folder, right click on the file or folder and go to **TortoiseSVN > Show Log...** to see the revision history.